# What does the 'this' word do in the following line of jQuery do?

Tags: jquery

What does the `this` part of the following line of jQuery do?

```
$('span:visible:first', this);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It restricts the search specified in the first argument to the context of the `this` object.

Only children of `this` that match the specified requirements will be selected. Without the context, the search will apply to the whole document.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> jQuery( selector, [ context ] )
>
> **context** A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

Comment: Should say `to the this object and it's children`

Comment: `this` will *not* match, it *only* looks inside children, here's a simple demo showing that: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/C4Unc/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe turning it around would be the simplest explanation, [it gets turned into this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/core.js#L174):

```
$(this).find('span:visible:first');
```

So it's using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get all descendants of `this` (whatever that element is) that match your `'span:visible:first'` selector.

Answer (score 0):

As the `this` keyword is the current object, it depends on where that code is placed. If you specify a second parameter, it's used as context for the search, i.e. it will only look for elements within that context.

If you use that on it's own, `this` is the same as `window` so it's the same as `$('span:visible:first', window)`.

If you use it inside an event handler, `this` is the element that the event was triggered on, so it will only seach for matches within that element.

Comment: Slight correction: the context defaults to `document` not `window`, which can be important when using `.context` later in the chain.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Right, I added `window` to the code so that it's completely equivalent.